# Pointers in memory changed when exiting if statement

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    const char* dog = "german shepard";

    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *doglistPath = @"/Users/doglover/doglist.plist";
    const char* doglistPath_cString = [doglistPath UTF8String];

    const char** doglist;

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:doglistPath]) {

        NSArray *doglistPlist = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:doglistPath];
        NSUInteger doglistPlistCount = [doglistPlist count];

        const char* doglist2[blacklistPlistCount];
        memset(doglist2, 0, sizeof doglist2);

        for (int index = 0; index < doglistPlistCount; index++) {
            const char *doglistName = [doglistPlist[index][@"type"] UTF8String];
            doglist2[index] = doglistName;
        }

        doglist = doglist2;
    }

    while(true) {
        NSLog(@"%s", *doglist);
        doglist++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There are 20 items in the plist.

Whenever I run this code, it prints only 4 items and gives Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

When I inspected the memory, when the runtime leaves the if-statement, the pointers in the doglist memory changes from :

```
B1 78 10 03 01 00 00 00
51 7B 10 03 01 00 00 00
01 7D 10 03 01 00 00 00
A1 7E 10 03 01 00 00 00
91 80 10 03 01 00 00 00
F8 74 10 03 01 00 00 00
11 83 10 03 01 00 00 00
C1 84 10 03 01 00 00 00
```

to

```
B1 78 10 03 01 00 00 00
51 7B 10 03 01 00 00 00
01 7D 10 03 01 00 00 00
A1 7E 10 03 01 00 00 00
40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
90 ED BF EF FE 7F 00 00
0E 00 B6 D1 69 DA B9 2C
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

In the changed memory, first four pointers do contain the items, but an error occurs at 0x40.

Why did the memory change after exiting the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

1. `+arrayWithContentsOfFile` is deprecated. You shouldn't be using it. Do you have control over the `doglist.plist` file? If so, I would suggest storing it using some other encoding mechanism, such as JSON.
2. Where is `blacklistPlistCount` declared? It's not in the code you posted, which prevents the code from compiling.
3. You are using `-[NSString UTF8String]` which returns a pointer to a buffer. However, this buffer is not guaranteed to exist past the lifetime of the string. Per the documentation:

> This C string is a pointer to a structure inside the string object, which may have a lifetime shorter than the string object and will certainly not have a longer lifetime. Therefore, you should copy the C string if it needs to be stored outside of the memory context in which you use this property.

4. Why are you using low-level C pointers at all to convert back and forth between C data structures and Objective-C types such as `NSArray` and  `NSString`? I would be using `NSMutableArray` for `doglist2` instead of using a C array. Unless you're doing certain specialized tasks, raw C pointers in Objective-C code is probably a code smell.

Anyway, point 3 is the most likely cause of your crash, because the buffer is long gone by the time you reach the `while` loop in your code.

Comment: What does it mean to "copy the C string"? If that's done, then will the c string persist through while loop?

Comment: It means to copy it, using `strcpy` or something similar. Then it will persist through the while loop. In fact, it will persist for the lifetime of the program unless you remember do deallocate the memory when you’re done with it. This is another reason you should take heed of my point number 4.